# Can I create a script to see which bots are crawling the site?

Tags: javascript, html, seo

I have a bunch of clients for whom I want to customize the site based on what bot is crawling their site.  Is it possible to create a script that detects which search engine bot is crawling the site and then track that or take another action?

Comment: Sure, it's possible to cater your pages for different clients/bots/etc. Just know that Google frowns upon (very much) such actions and your page rank may be hurt by doing this. Here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en

Comment: @JackPattishall Thanks! Even if i am a 3rd party JS that the client will place it on the site?

Answer (score 1):

Many bots got an specific User Agent. You could filter out the bots with it and then just do whatever action you want to do. Not sure if you can do it from frontend (the javascript tag is present here, unless we are talking about node.js).

For an instance googlebot user agent:

`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)`

From PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)') { 
  doSomething();
}
```

The reason why I think you can't do it from frontend js is because many bots don't actually use javascript, they just read the http responses.

**Edit**:  There are some bots that do interpret Javascript (googlebot is one of them), although to a certain extent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because **JavaScript** (files or snippets) **is not crawled by the bots**. Only your text and you are html are crawled. Basically all the content served by your "server side" (your HTTP Response).

Comment: For google, this isn't true anymore. They're executing JavaScript and considering things like blocking script, cloaking, etc. to determine page rank. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html